# How to store a table of values for multiple uses of program?

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I'm using Qt and I would like to store data that is an array in the form of a table for multiple uses of the application. When I only needed a few ints not in the form of a table I just used a text file but if I use that for this it may be a bit unorganized. What would be the best way of doing this.

Comment: use a database, in your case I would choose sqlite since it is minimalist.

Comment: To avoid additional dependencies such as databases or xml parsers simply use `QSettings` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I find your question a little unclear but it appears to me that you just want to create a table from an array. [Here](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/sql-presenting.html) is the documentation on doing so by Qt. For more on arrays I recommend [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/arrays/).